# Disconnect from one domain and connect to another domain

Tags: networking, windows-8, dns, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-domain

I had old domain lets call it "A". There was 5 computers connected to domain "A". Now I have just created domain "B". Now I want all 5 computers connected to domain B. It is giving me error: `"The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted"`

I tried another computer that wasn't connected to domain. It was on WORKGROUP. I changed the DNS IP Address and add it. It works perfect. Why I can't add computers from domain A to Domain B? I eve tried taking them out of domain A and put under WORKGROUP then tried adding them back to Domain B. Still no luck. BTW: DNS Settings are set on all 5 computers.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Are the network AND workgroup/homegroup settings on the 5 computers IDENTICAL to the "other" computer?

Comment: @pattern86 Yes I switched all 5 computers to WORKGROUP and changed all the settings (same as a computer which wasn't in the domain)

Comment: These two links may assist you, especially the second one. I don't have equipment to test at the moment. [Join a domain, workgroup, or homegroup](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/join-domain-workgroup-homegroup), [How to Join Windows 8.1 to a Domain](http://www.tomsitpro.com/articles/how-to-join-windows-8.1-to-domain,2-735.html)